# How to keep controller in only one orientation?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two classes which subclass from `UIViewController`. `PortraitViewController` and `LandscapeViewController`.

These classes have their vars `shouldAutorotate`, `supportedInterfaceOrientations` and `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` with override implementation so they can stick to portrait or landscape orientation accordingly.

My application accepts Portrait and Landscape mode.

Now, I also have:

1. `ViewController1` which subclasses from `PortraitViewController`
2. `ViewController2` which subclasses from `LandscapeViewController`

When I show `ViewController1` with a `UINavigationController` attached to it, it sticks with portrait as expected.

When I show `ViewController2` with a `UINavigationController` attached to it, as a modal nav on top of `ViewController1`, it sticks with landscape as expected.

There's an extension for `UINavigationController` which also overrides the vars mentioned above, but it reads properties from the `visibleController` parameter.

But when I dismiss `ViewController2`, `ViewController1` appears in landscape.

How can I make `ViewController1` stick in portrait mode, regardless of what I show on top of it?

Note: Every time the device is in portrait mode.

EDIT:

Here's a demo project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ishe88e1x81nzlp/DemoOrientationApp.zip?dl=0

Comment: Is there a navigation controller anywhere in this story? Please make sure you are describing the view controller situation fully and accurately.

Comment: Also could you define some terms? What is "extends"? Do you mean "is a subclass of"? And what exactly is a "modal nav" — _exactly_?

Comment: edited question with nav info, and yes, it's subclass.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry, I need to see a diagram and actual code. If the situation was just what you said originally, this problem would not be happening. So I need the truth and sufficient information. It might be best to reproduce the whole thing as a downloadable demo project.

Comment: You see, I believe you do not have a "modal" anything. I believe you are in a navigation interface and you are _pushing_ view controller 2 onto the navigation controller. And that means that what you are trying to do is _impossible_. I don't care how much fiddling you do, you cannot push B on top of A and have A and B have distinct orientations.

Comment: Also, there is a built-in way that UINavigationController can be told what the orientation should be, but what you are doing is not it.

Comment: I can prepare a demo project in the next 10 mins an attach it in the question.

Comment: That would be excellent! Thank you

Comment: @matt added to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The visibleViewController is either the top view controller of the navigation stack or a view controller presented from the navigation controller.

So, when you present the second navigation controller, the first navigation controller reads the second navigation controller property which passes back the landscape view controller's property.

What you need to use instead is topViewController. That way, the setting is limited to the view controller stack.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so:

Throw away your UINavigationControllerExtension.

Change your Info.plist so that we launch only into portrait:

[image]

(Delete items 1 and 2.)

In the app delegate, add this code, to allow us to rotate to landscape *after* launch:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .all
}
```

In ViewController, fix the code as follows:

```
class ViewController: PortraitViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.delegate = self
    }
    func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
    @IBAction func showView(_ sender: Any) {
        let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nav.delegate = vc
        present(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In ViewController2, fix the code as follows:

```
class ViewController2: LandscapeViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationControllerSupportedInterfaceOrientations(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return self.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
    func navigationControllerPreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation(_ navigationController: UINavigationController) -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return self.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    }
    @IBAction func dismiss(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

The app now behaves as desired.